Using the LIKE operator to look for matches in a json-like string
I need to find those notifications that have the eventCode set to REFUND.
Here is the object stored in the DB:
{
    "target": "target",
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
        "x-forwarded-host": "x-forwarded-host",
        "x-real-ip": "x-real-ip",
        "x-forwarded-for": "x-forwarded-for",
        "x-forwarded-proto": "x-forwarded-proto",
        "host": "host",
        "connection": "connection",
        "content-length": "content-length",
        "cf-ipcountry": "cf-ipcountry",
        "accept-encoding": "accept-encoding",
        "cf-ray": "cf-ray",
        "cdn-loop": "cdn-loop",
        "cf-connecting-ip": "cf-connecting-ip",
        "cf-visitor": "cf-visitor",
        "traceparent": "traceparent",
        "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "user-agent": "user-agent"
    },
    "body": "{\"live\":\"true\",\"notificationItems\":[{\"NotificationRequestItem\":{\"additionalData\":{\"hmacSignature\":\"yadayadayada\",\"bookingDate\":\"2023-01-10T11:54:37Z\"},\"amount\":{\"currency\":\"EUR\",\"value\":2500},\"eventCode\":\"REFUND\",\"eventDate\":\"2023-01-10T11:53:43+02:00\",\"merchantAccountCode\":\"yadayada\",\"merchantReference\":\"yadayada\",\"originalReference\":\"yadayada\",\"paymentMethod\":\"mc\",\"pspReference\":\"yadayada\",\"reason\":\"\",\"success\":\"true\"}}]}"
}

I'm using a zsh terminal and trying to write a query that would parse that body string:
select * from notifications where order_id=123456 and json_extract(data, '$.body') like '%\"eventCode\":\"REFUND\"%' \G

It does not work. By trial and error I found out that this works:
select * from notifications where id=123456 and json_extract(data, '$.body') like '%\"REFUND%' \G

but this does not:
select * from notifications where id=123456 and json_extract(data, '$.body') like '%:\"REFUND%' \G

Looks like the semicolon breaks it somehow.
What am I doing wrong?
UPDATE:
So I incorporated this query into a bigger one to look like this:
SELECT concat(date(o.timestamp), ' ', extract(hour FROM o.timestamp), 'h') AS date,
       time_to_sec((timediff(n.timestamp, o.timestamp))) / 60 AS 'timedelay (minutes)',
       o.id AS order_id,
       c.user_id AS user_id
FROM notifications n
         JOIN orders AS o ON n.order_id = o.id
         JOIN credentials AS c ON o.credential_id = c.id
         JOIN merchants AS m ON c.merchant_id = m.id
         JOIN providers AS p ON m.provider_id = p.id
         CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(
            JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(n.data, '$.body')),
            '$.notificationItems[*]' COLUMNS (
            eventCode VARCHAR(20) PATH '$.NotificationRequestItem.eventCode'
        )) AS j
WHERE p.name = 'adyen'
  AND o.timestamp > '2024-04-11'
  AND time_to_sec((timediff(n.timestamp, o.timestamp))) / 60 > 60
  AND o.type = 'payment'
  AND j.eventCode = 'AUTHORISATION';

Except now it deals with a different event type.
This query errors out with ERROR 3141 (22032): Invalid JSON text in argument 1 to function json_table: "Invalid value." at position 0.
One important detail here is that the tables notifications, credentials, merchants have a field called data. It looks like the query gets confused despite the use of aliases and the presence of no compelling reason for ambiguity.
One more observation:
This query
SELECT n.id FROM notifications AS n
JOIN orders o ON n.order_id = o.id
WHERE n.provider_id = 1
AND o.type > 'payment'
AND JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(n.data,'$.body')), '$.notificationItems[0].NotificationRequestItem.eventCode') = 'AUTHORISATION'
LIMIT 5;

Errors out with ERROR 3141 (22032): Invalid JSON text in argument 1 to function json_extract: "The document is empty." at position 0..
But this query:
SELECT n.id FROM notifications AS n
WHERE n.order_id IN (
    SELECT o.id FROM orders AS o WHERE o.type = 'payment'
)
AND n.provider_id = 1
AND JSON_EXTRACT(
    JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(n.data,'$.body')),
    '$.notificationItems[0].NotificationRequestItem.eventCode'
) = 'AUTHORISATION'
LIMIT 5 \G

works just fine.
I've been working on rewriting the query in such a way that I could
avoid using joins, but so far didn't come up with a decent solution.
As for the version:
mysql> SELECT Version();
+-----------+
| Version() |
+-----------+
| 8.0.35-27 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


show what you are actually doing in zsh.  or alternatively, do echo before your command and see what is there after shell escapes and debug that part yourself, then show us the echoed query to help with the mysql part

@ysth I'm not sure I understood what you mean by "do echo". Once I executed mysql -u qwerty -p and entered 12345 I can only execute SQL commands. The commands I executed are shown above.

you probably want something like json_search(json_unquote(json_extract(data,'$.body')), ...)

ah, so you aren't entering this in zsh, you are entering it in the msyql command line client.  "using a zsh terminal" made it sound like you were using zsh to send the command to the mysql client.  never mind then.

@ysth aah, yes, my bad, this redundant piece of information is really confusing...

You linked to an issue with PingCap TiDB. Are you using TiDB? You tagged your question MySQL.

@BillKarwin oops, right, there's another article...I linked a wrong one, sorry, anyways, I'm using MySQL.

I assume your notificationItems array may have more than one element, and you need to search for your REFUND value in any element of the array.
If so, you need to use JSON_TABLE():
SELECT n.id, j.eventCode
FROM notifications AS n
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(
  JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.body')),
  '$.notificationItems[*]' COLUMNS (
    eventCode VARCHAR(20) PATH '$.NotificationRequestItem.eventCode'
  )) AS j
WHERE n.id=123456 AND j.eventCode = 'REFUND';


I incorporated it into my query, somehow I'm getting this error: ERROR 3141 (22032): Invalid JSON text in argument 1 to function json_table: "Invalid value." at position 0.. I checked the data for validity by using JSON_VALID and the data seems okay, I tried quite a bit of everything and still getting this error...it's not clear to me what is breaking the query...

On every row of your table, or just a specific row? What's the content in the data column on that row? Also, can you run SELECT VERSION(); and tell me exactly what it returns?

Done. I've edited my update into the original question and explained the issue I am facing now in more detail. Looks like some ambiguity is taking place here. Could you please have a look?

This happens after a few minutes. For example the code you posted above works just great. But with all these joins it fails with this error after running for a couple of minutes...of course those data fields on other tables that I mentioned above have different data. But this ambiguity is not supposed to happen...

I have no idea. It is not MySQL's behavior in my experience that it randomly forgets which column to reference, even when you use qualified identifiers. I think if that were such a bug in MySQL, it would have been big news immediately. It's more likely that your data is malformed.

I also had this idea in mind, my first thoughts: "some data is malformed", right, to exclude this scenario I ran a query checking validity with the help of JSON_VALID. The data looks valid. How would you check validity then? I've also tried adding joins to that query of your and it still worked.

I did it in a few ways, one way to just add AND JSON_VALID(n.data).

also added to check if the body is "clean" using AND JSON_VALID(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(n.data, '$.body'))) and yes, this time around the error was not thrown which means you're right. I will investigate more how this data is corrupted then, cos it comes from a trusted source and presumable should not get corrupted when written into the DB.

Did you not define the data column as data type JSON? That would force all data stored in that column to be valid JSON format. Oh, of course, not — it's JSON-within-JSON. The data type can't enforce that.

well this code dates back to the prehistoric times and existed long before me, it was not done of course...
